# Is there a certification for Mariadb?

Tags: mariadb

Is there an official certification for Mariadb?
And if there is how can I find the next exam days?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can contact MariaDB to find out how/when/where you can take an exam. They state:

"This certification exam, proctored and administered by MariaDB"

on:

https://mariadb.com/resources/datasheets/certification-mariadb/

There is also preparation material to download there.

Comment: The certification exam has so far only been offered at the annual MariaDB conferences - at M|17, at M|18 and again next month at [MariaDB OpenWorks](https://mariadb.com/openworks/certification/). All these conferences have been at the same place, New York City, USA.